# How does Fiddler download files from replay sessions?

Tags: fiddler

I am new to fiddler and have been analyzing some session archives containing malicious file downloads from about two years ago. The malicious sites in question have been taken down already. On replaying the sessions on IE, the files are attempted to download again on my VM. I am curious to know as to how fiddler is able to do this even when the site hosting the content has been taken offline.

Appreciate any thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the "malicious sites" pages where hosted on one place and the "malicious file downloads" where hosted on another place. The website can be down but the host for the files is probably still up. Fiddler is just replaying the HTTP requests.